# How do I export the Serenity Report Result to HP ALM

Tags: jenkins, cucumber-serenity

I have my Jenkins Job running for API Automation coded in JAVA. It generates the Cucumber - Serenity Report in the form of index.html. I need to export/push the test execution result in HP ALM to track my execution results in HP ALM

Gone through the threads and it talks about configuring the testresult.xml file in Jenkins. In my case it is generating the index.html file as the test execution in Jenkins.

Runner File:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true, strict = false,
    features = "src/test/resources/features/",
    glue = { "com.pearson.glp.qe.stepdefinations.assignmentmanagement"    },
    tags = { "@Regression" }, plugin = { "html:target/cucumber",
            "json:target/cucumber.json", "junit:target/cucumber.xml" })
```

I am expecting this test result to be exported and available in HP ALM to track the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) which has Jenkins plugin and could upload your Serenity JSON report into ALM.
Here is a link for the docs: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/ci-integration/jenkins/#-export-tests-results

Disclaimer: I'm developing Bumblebee.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. The bumblebee plug-in is a commercial plug-in and I am looking for a open source.